# Getting class-based CSS attribute via JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, size

I have JS code where I try to determine if the size of an image was explicitly set via CSS or the by using the width/height attributes. If so, I respect the set sizes, otherwise I execute code to size the image myself. Here is the code. It uses some jQuery, so `image` is a jQuery object and `image[0]` accesses the actual DOM element:

```
if (image.attr('height') == undefined && image[0].style.height.length == 0) {
    image.data("explicit_height", false);
    //Do stuff to the image size here
} else {
    image.data("explicit_height", true);
}

// ...SAME FOR WIDTH...
```

The problem I am facing is that this code works fine as long as either the height/width or style *attributes* are used. When the height/width is set via a CSS selector (for example a class selector), the code is NOT working. The code is executing on window load.

Anyone got an idea why this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to use the `images` Collection? Your code says `image` and `image[0]`. Please explain. You would have to use jQuery's `.height()` method or `getComputedStyle()` and `.currentStyle()` in plain JavaScript. You can`t retrieve using `style.height`.

Comment: oh yeah, I'm sorry about that. `image` is a jQuery object, so `image[0]` is the underlying native DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `getComputedStyle` or `currentStyle` to get styles set in a stylesheet (the latter works in earlier versions of IE.)  `style` will only return inline style properties.

```
(image.getAttribute('height') == null
 && ((window.getComputedStyle(image)||image.currentStyle)['height']) == '0px') ?
    //do stuff
:
    //do other stuff
```

You could also map the evaluation of that statement to an object of functions:

```
function foo() { image.data("explicit_height", false) }
function bar() { image.data("explicit_height", true) }

var bool = ( image.getAttribute('height') == null
 && ((window.getComputedStyle(image)||image.currentStyle)['height']) == '0px' ),
fn = {
    true:foo,
    false:bar
}[bool]();
```

You'll need to play around with `image.getAttribute('height') == null` and the statement that follows that, because they are based on default values in the browser, which could be different (I only tested on Firefox 26 for Mac 10.9, and the default values where there is no height attribute is `null` and where there is no `height` declared in a stylesheet is 0px.)

### Updated Answer

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p2eB/2/):

```
var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

function foo() { image.setAttribute("name", "foo") }
function bar() { image.setAttribute("name", "bar") }

var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;

function isHeightDefinedInStyleSheets(tag) {
    for(i in styleSheets) {
        var rules = styleSheets[i]['cssRules'||'rules'];        
        if(rules!==undefined) {
            for(j in rules) {
                if(rules[j]['style']!==undefined&&rules[j].selectorText===tag) {
                    if(parseInt(rules[j]['style']['height'])>0) {
                        console.log(true);
                         return true;   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(false);
    return false;
}

var fn = {
    true:foo,
    false:bar
}[!isHeightDefinedInStyleSheets('img') && image.getAttribute('height') == null]();
```

This function will check the stylesheets themselves for whether a rule exists (which is different than `getComputedStyle`, which will get the style of the element based on its computed value, regardless of whether the value was defined inline or in a stylesheet, etc.) Its return value is passed along as a key with the return value checking whether `height` was defined inline as an attribute to the image. If the statement evaluates "true", it will execute the "true" function (`foo`) in the object `fn`; otherwise it will execute `bar`.

I haven't dealt with the `styleSheets` property before, so the code needs to be cleaned up quite a bit, but it demonstrates the basic point.  Also, if you have a collection of `img` elements, you'll need to implement a looping function to iterate through each element in the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the response, seems you are partly right. `style` only works for the inline style attribute. The problem I have is that I want to find out if the image was sized via html or css. Using `getComputedStyle` / `currentStyle` will return the native size of the image if no size was given in html/css, at least in my tests. Is there any way to figure out if html's width/height or css's width/height were set on the image?

Comment: When you say "css's width/height", are you wanting to see if the width/height was set in the stylesheet, or using "style=" inside the element?

Comment: both, actually. I am writing a script where the default behaviour is to adjust the size of all images in some way - only if the user/web designer explicitly sized an image (either using stylesheets, inline style or width/height attribute) I want my script to not alter the size.

Comment: @BlackWolf, Check out the updated answer. That function will check whether height for any given tag name (passed as a parameter) was defined in the stylesheet itself.

Comment: Thanks you, that works  as long as I know the CSS rule I am looking for, which is unfortunately not always the case in my script. I think I will probably end up making the assumption that if width and height are the same as the native width/height, they were not set.